# Loop through word with letter evaluated as False?

Tags: python, string, loops, boolean

The following is code from a class example.
What is bothering me is this section:

```
up = False
for i in x:
    if up:
       i=i.upper()
```

I don't really understand how a letter in the word being iterated through could be evaluated as False or True?

Here is the entire question:

```
def mirror(x):
  return x+x[::-1]

def steps(x):
  result=""
  x=x.lower()
  up=False
  for i in x:
     if up:
       i=i.upper()
     result+=i
     up = not up
  return result

print(steps("jabberwocky"))
print(steps(mirror("CAT")))
```

Comment: The variable that is evaluated in the `if` statement is `up`, not one of the letters (these are stored in `i`).

Comment: What language is this? It looks like python, but you really should tell us. Ideally, through tagging. Or should we treat it as pseudocode?

Comment: @JanDvorak sorry it is Python. New to the site and I didn't know - thank you :)

Comment: @JanDvorak Python is so readable, it looks like pseudocode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a loop iterating over each character in your string. `up` is a `boolean` variable initially set to `False`. So initially you have

```
 if False:
   i=i.upper()
```

At the end of your for loop you have `up` set to `True` (`up = not up` always toggles the `boolean` value - `False` becomes `True` and `True` becomes `False`). So the second iteration of your for loop you have

```
if True
  i=i.upper()
```

This loop will take in a string and every other character will be uppercased:

```
>>> print(steps("jabberwocky"))
jAbBeRwOcKy
```

Answer (score 0):

What steps function is doing is:

1) Set all x characters to lowercase

2) Set a variable "up" initially to False

3) For each letter in x,

- if the variable up is true, then make that letter uppercase
- append that letter to result
- set up to its opposite (if true => false // if false => true)

4) Return result